# DJI Windows SDK: Suport for Mavic 2 Pro

Tags: dji-sdk

I see the Windows SDK is listed as supporting only Phantom 2 and Mavic Air.

Is support for Mavic 2 Pro planned, and if so, does anyone know approximately when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[4.9 SDK](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/product_introduction.html) lists the Mavic 2 Enterprise Dual, Mavic 2 Enterprise, Mavic 2 Pro and Mavic 2 Zoom as supported.